# How to bring back Sleep option Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

The option to Sleep has disappeared from my Windows 8. I've tried going to Control Panel, Power Options, Choosing what the power button does, turn-on/configure unavailable options, and stuff. It really has just disappeared. How can I bring back the Sleep option in Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Power Options** in **Control Panel**, then click on the left side **Require a password on wakeup**. When you get to that screen, click **Change settings that are currently unavailable**. After you authenticate as an administrator, check the box titled **Sleep** under **Shutdown settings** and click **Save changes** and close the window.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following registry key

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\Microsoft\PortableOperatingSystem]
"Sleep"=-

restart the computer and check.

Comment: Hi techmate, be specific pls, Im not so familiar dealing with registries: I was abe to go up to this only, I open RUN, then type regedit, then go up to this only: 
"[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies\", then after that, there's only one there = Default REG_SZ (value not set). Could someone tell me step by step.

Comment: @AsktoGainknowledge navigate to that Policies key as you did, right-click it and choose *New* &rarr; *Key*, enter the name `Microsoft` and confirm with `Enter`. This time right-click newly created `Microsoft` key and create new key `PortableOperatingSystem`. Then right-click it, *New* &rarr; *DWORD value*. Type the name *Sleep*, double-click it and enter value of `0`. (`-` is probably a typo because it doesn't make much sense)

Answer (score -1):

The `Sleep` option is still in Windows 8. Go to the `charms` menu, click `Settings` then `Power` and you should see `Sleep`.

Comment: Only Shut Down and Hibernate were there, nothing more, nothing else !

Comment: Normally, there should be Sleep, Shutdown, and Restart

Comment: But unfortunately no. All the drop down lists say: Do Nothing, Hibernate, Shut Down. At the bottom, Hibernate, Shut Down, Enable Hybrid etc, something like that.

Comment: Have you tried pressing `Ctrl+Alt+Del` then clicking the small `power` symbol. That should give you 3 options: `Sleep`, `Shutdown`, and `Restart`

Comment: I just tried it, only 2 options were there: Shut Down and Restart.